# LaTeXで1ページの中の余白を2つ設定したい

Tags: latex

pLaTeXを使用しています。ドキュメントクラスはjlreqです。
1ページの中のページレイアウトを変更したいです。
\newgeometryで左右余白を変更して文を打ち込み\restoregeometryで戻した後、本文を入力するとその本文は次のページへ移動してしまいます。
私のやりたいことはタイトルや概要といった部分は左右の余白を10mm狭くして入力、その後に続く本文は元の余白に戻して入力、これを1ページの中で行いたいです。

何か良い案はありますでしょうか。
タイトルや概要といった部分のみ左右の余白を変更できればベストだと考えています。
（\hspace*{}は既に試しましたが行頭と行末が変わるだけでタイトルや概要といった部分全体の余白が変わることはありませんでした）

Answer (score 5, accepted):

段落の左右の余白（マージン）を決定する LaTeX 標準の寸法コマンドは `\leftskip` と `\rightskip` です．これらを一時的に変更することで，同じページ内でも特定の段落のみ左右の余白を変更することができます．

ここでは calc パッケージを用いて「現在の余白プラス 10mm 大きな余白」などの相対的な指定を行う例を示します：

```
%#!platex
\documentclass{jlreq}

\usepackage{bxjalipsum}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\jalipsum[1-2]{wagahai}

{\setlength{\leftskip}{\leftskip+10truemm}\setlength{\rightskip}{\rightskip+10truemm}%
\jalipsum[3]{wagahai}\par}% グループ内に \par が必要な点に注意！

\jalipsum[4]{wagahai}

\end{document}
```

なお `\leftskip` と `\rightskip` は「段落の終了時点」で設定されている値が有効になるので，`{` ... `}` によるグループ内で一時的に値の変更を行った場合は，そのグループの内部で改段落を起こす（具体的には `\par` を明示的に書くなど）必要がある点に留意してください．

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。\jalipsumやcalcパッケージというのが今一つわからなかったので\leftskip、\rightskipをそのまま使いました。そして望み通りのものが出来ました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 所望の結果が得られたようでよかったです．補足ですが `bxjalipsum` パッケージはダミーテキスト（上記の例では「吾輩は猫である」テキスト）の出力に用いています．`calc` パッケージは `\setlength` の設定値で `+` などの演算子を使用するのに必要です．

Answer (score 0):

`\newgeometry`はページレイアウトの変更に使うものなので強制的に改ページされるのだと思います。

単に字下げをするのであればindentが使えます。

```
 \usepackage{indent}
```

```
\begin{indentation}{-3zw}{1zw}
見出し
\end{indentation}
```

`jlreq`を使っているのであれば見出しの書式を変えるなど構造的な文書にした方がよいと思います。

---

確認した環境はubuntuです。indent.styは次の手順でインストールしています。

- インストール先の確認

```
ls -ld $(sudo kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL)/tex/platex
```

- インストール先のディレクトリが存在しなければ作成
- インストール

```
wget https://ftp.kddilabs.jp/CTAN/macros/latex209/contrib/misc/indent.sty
sudo cp indent.sty インストール先のディレクトリ/
sudo mktexlsr
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。一番簡単そうだったので試したのですがパッケージがそもそもないようで使用できず断念しました。パッケージのダウンロードなどはよく理解できていないのでまたいつか挑戦します。ありがとうございました。

Comment: TEXMFDIST（上記の例では `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/` ですが，これはシステムや設定により可変です）は手動で変更を加えるべき TEXMF ツリーではないので，当然パッケージの手動インストール先にすべきではありません．手動でパッケージをインストールするなら TEXMFHOME（自分だけが使う場合）または TEXMFLOCAL（システムにインストールする場合．`mktexlsr` の実行が必要）にインストールを行うべきです．それぞれのご使用環境でのパス位置は `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME` のようにすれば確認できます．

Comment: @wtsnjp コメントありがとうございました。「kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFLOCAL」で調べたディレクトリの下に「tex/platex」を作成し、そこにindent.styを配置しなおしました。